# The question is to find the equation in $s$ that expresses this equality. Artin's book problem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The problem from Artin's book states:

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{bmatrix}$$ be a real $2\times 2$ matrix. The condition that a column vector $V$ be an eigenvector for left multiplication by $A$ is that $AX = Y$, which means that the slopes $s= {x_2\over x_1} $ and $s' = {y_2 \over y_1}$ are equal.

The question is to find the equation in $s$ that expresses this equality.

**My attempt:**

$$AX=Y=\lambda X$$
Thus, $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
ax_1+bx_2\\
cx_1+dx_2\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Therefore, $$ax_1+bx_2=y_1=\lambda x_1$$
$$cx_1+dx_2=y_2=\lambda x_2$$

The next step is to divide each equation by $x_1$ and get:
$$ a + b{x_2 \over x_1} = {y_1\over x_1} = \lambda $$
$$ c + d{x_2 \over x_1} = {y_2\over x_1} = \lambda {x_2 \over x_1} $$

Then I am dividing $2^{nd}$ equation by the $1^{st}$ one and getting:
$${c \over a} + {d \over b} = {y_2 \over y_1} = {x_2 \over x_1} $$

Any corrections and further suggestions are more than welcome. Thank you in advance for your effort.

Comment: do you know how to find the determinant of a square matrix, especially size 2 by 2?

Comment: I do not see any correlation b/w finding the determinant and the problem solution here. And yes, I know how to find the determinant.

Comment: $$\frac{c+d\frac{x_2}{x_1}}{a+b\frac{x_2}{x_1}}\neq \frac{c}{a} + \frac{d}{b}$$

Comment: Depending on the organization of the book, there may appear to be a few steps.... You are asking for $(A - \lambda I)X = 0.$ This means that $A - \lambda I$ must be singular. In turn this means that the determinant of $A- \lambda I$ must be zero; once you know the eigenvalues $\lambda,$ in turn you can ask about $X.$ Under some circumstances, the eigenvalue(s) may not be real numbers...

Comment: @WillJagy, ok thank you. I will take it into consideration.